# reportchef error

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am try to reports in chef with `chef_handler` cookbook and `reportchef`
When I try to upload this to the server:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

class ReportChef < Chef::Handler
def initialize(opts = nil)
@opts = opts
unless opts[:api_key]
  Chef::Application.fatal!("No ReportChef API Key set")
end
end

def report
params = @opts.merge({ node_name: run_status.node.fqdn })

if run_status.failed?
  params[:last_run_successful] = false
  params[:exception] = run_status.formatted_exception
  params[:backtrace] = run_status.backtrace.join("\n")
else
  params[:last_run_successful] = true
end

uri = URI.parse("http://reportchef.com/api/v1/reports")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(params)
response = http.request(request)
end
end
```

Error

```
knife cookbook upload reportchef -c /etc/chef/knife.rb
Uploading reportchef     [1.0.1]
FATAL: Cookbook file files/default/reportchef.rb has a ruby syntax error:
FATAL: /software/chef-repo/cookbooks/reportchef/files/default/reportchef.rb:13: syntax    
error
FATAL:     params = @opts.merge({ node_name: run_status.node.fqdn })
FATAL:                                      ^
FATAL: /software/chef-repo/cookbooks/reportchef/files/default/reportchef.rb:13:     syntax   
error
FATAL:     params = @opts.merge({ node_name: run_status.node.fqdn })
FATAL:
```

What happened?

It´s downloaded code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using Ruby 1.8 on your server and in 1.8 there is some specific syntax sugar missing that allows you in 1.9 to write `{a: 'b'}` (equivalent to `{:a => 'b'}`).

You should try to get Ruby 1.9 on your server or encourage the author to create backward compatibility (not so recommended because 1.8 is unsupported imho).